# Performance Tuning WCF Service

Tags: wcf, performance

What is the single most important performance tuning area for a WCF Web service?

- ASP.net Thread settings?
- WCF throttling?

Answer (score 5):

Please take a look at the articles and whitepapers below. I think they should give you MUCH more concrete performance considerations to explore, and likely some very practical settings to tweak, optimize, or change. I posted this answer in another question as well, but I think it'll be useful for anybody who comes across this question as well.

Off-hand, without even knowing your scenario, you can't say X throttle settings are more important than Y thread settings.

[Performance Tuning WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273113.aspx)

[Optimizing WCF Web Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee377061%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

[Using ServiceThrottlingBehavior to Control WCF Service Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114.aspx)

[Transport Quotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731078.aspx)

[Optimizing IIS Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee377050%28v=bts.10%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Performance Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668225.aspx)

[A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to see is if WCF is your bottleneck or is it something else (like your DB calls etc.). Most performance improvement can be done by the usual stuff (nothing special to WCF) like caching, optimised DB access, choice of data structures, alogirthms etc.'

Something specific to WCF is to design all web service calls to be stateless so that they can be easily scaled on multiple servers using load balancing. Try to have coarse grain services that are not very chatty. If your service consumer is .Net based use the Net.Tcp protoccol, it has much better marshalling than SOAP/HTTP.
WCF throttles quite conservatively, you will do better to increase the throttling limits.

Answer (score 0):

There's so much that depends upon your application design, hardware and load.

If I had to pick one technique, it would probably be using single call objects.

Throttling is helpful once you have a feel for the peak load your system can handle.

Answer (score 0):

This article by [Mikayel Vardanyan](https://www.monitis.com/blog/author/mvardan/) was very useful for me:
https://www.monitis.com/blog/top-8-application-based-iis-server-performance-tips/

In summary:

1. Remove competing, unused, and duplicate applications and services
2. Optimize content usage
3. Limit the queue length for application pools
4. Enable IIS HTTP compression
5. Grow a Web Garden on IIS
6. Recycling application pools
7. Reduce Logging Frequency
8. Use the Expires header in IIS7