# Optimizing wcf service in IIS

Tags: wcf

I am hosting a ASP.NET web site containing a wcf web service in IIS 7. The web service is exposed using a .svc file that resides inside the web site's virtual directory.

There's section is this document about optimizing the web service performance by removing unnecessary http modules:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377061(v=bts.10).aspx

My question is how can I do that in the web config without affecting the web site? My ASP.NET web site contains authentication stuff and definitely requires some of those modules (eg, FormsAuthentication). Is there a way to enable those modules only for the web site but disable them when the clients access the web service?

Thanks

Comment: Could you separate the service from the website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance Tuning WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264366/performance-tuning-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0):

You should separete your project into two (web and Service).

After that, create a website into IIS and add those two application separatedly, like that:

[image: IIS Config]

That way you can handle different configurations for each site, and configure the modules for a especific "project" (like wcf service).